# What part is causing my post request to spotify's API to fail?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, spotify

So this is my first project in javascript and also the first one having to do with any sort of API. At the moment, my mission is to get a list of the top 3 artists from someone's spotify account.

To accomplish this, I've made a simple HTML page with a button and put all the functionality in 2 js files within my project.

I've implemented the authentication with PKCE as indicated in the docs, however, when it comes to the part where a request token needs to be parsed from the URL after being redirected back from the authentication endpoint, it seems to fail. I've looked at the code for a while and can't see what's going wrong to cause this. All help is appreciated, but please try to explain in a way a beginner to JS and APIs would understand. Thanks.

```
//This is the function that connects the user to the authentication server

function authenticate(){
    const clientId = 'f101df3a42484b9e9aa1d1aa34fa5770';
    const redirectUri = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html';
    
    let codeVerifier = generateRandomString(128);
    
    generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier).then(codeChallenge => {
      let state = generateRandomString(16);
      let scope = 'user-top-read';
    
      localStorage.setItem('code-verifier', codeVerifier);
    
      let args = new URLSearchParams({
        response_type: 'code',
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: scope,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        state: state,
        code_challenge_method: 'S256',
        code_challenge: codeChallenge
      });
    
      window.location = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + args;
    });
    
};
```

```
//This is the code that triggers after user is redirected back to previous page to parse the new token and use it for the request for the top 3 artists

function redirectToken(){
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let code = urlParams.get('code');
  let codeVerifier = localStorage.getItem('code_verifier');
  const redirectUri = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html';
  const clientId = "f101df3a42484b9e9aa1d1aa34fa5770";
  let body = new URLSearchParams({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    client_id: clientId,
    code_verifier: codeVerifier
  });
  const response = fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: body
})
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('HTTP status ' + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    localStorage.setItem('access-token', data.access_token);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
};
```

I've tried changing the code_verifier into a global variable as I thought saving it to localStorage was not enough for it to work when being referenced from a different function but this didn't seem to change anything, the post request in the redirectToken() function still returns 400.[image]

**Edit 2:**

[image: the new errors]

This is the function which calls the redirectToken() function and contains the GET request which is returning a 401.

```
   function getTopArtists(){
    const url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists?limit=3&offset=3&time_range=short_term";
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+redirectToken());
    xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(data.items); // This will log the top 3 artists to the console
    } else {
        console.log('Error!');
    }
  };
      xhr.send();

  };
```

Comment: We need to see what error detail is being returned with the http-400. That should provide clues about what is wrong. Add console.log(‘error response’, response) before throw new Error and add what gets written to the browser console to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that Spotify is objecting to the redirect_uri being provided.

```
  const redirectUri = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html';
```

In my experience, with other OAuth2 providers, not Spotify, is that the redirect_uri must match exactly what is registered against the client_id - the http/s part, the hostname, the port and (sometimes) the path.

As a diagnostic step, try putting in the exactly redirect_uri and see if it gets beyond the 400. Because you are not actually using the redirect_uri in this step it should not matter what you send.

Unfortunately the extra logging I suggested is insufficient because it does not show the body of the 400 response but it at least has one that we can unpack. Update the `!response.ok` logic to the following. It is also an improvement in the error handling.

```
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.error('error response', response);
        response.json().then(json => {
            console.error('error body json', json);
            throw new Error('HTTP status ' + response.status + ': ' + json.error + ":" + json.error_description);
        });
      throw new Error('HTTP status ' + response.status);
    }
```

Please add the logged object to the question with everything expanded.

Comment: Hi, sorry for getting back to you so late, been busy with some holidays. I've tried what you said and it showed me that there was a mistake in the code I copied from the spotify dev website, I changed that and then it started giving me a different error. And now a new 401 error has appeared from a GET request from a different function in the code which calls the redirectToken() function to return the value for the access token. All relevant info has been edited onto question.

Comment: Also, the URI is probably not the issue as it is a 100% match for the one on the app dashboard on spotify developers.

Comment: If you don’t have the correct token then all calls that need one will 401. The problem is still in the code to token exchange. We still need to see what the error is underlying the 400 in fetching the token. That is the change I suggested here and the log I requested. Without that I can’t help you.

Comment: Hi, I followed your advice with the logging and fixed it, the problem was that the generated access token was not being saved because the response.json() was not being returned. It works now, thank you very much for your help.